# Searching specific row for a particular data by the use of cursor in PL/SQL in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am new to PL/SQL and I am trying to search a specific data from schema. I want to use nested cursors and make the query dynamic. Please help me out with the approach.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please give more details - like what have you tried till now ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which uses a loop (though, not nested loops, as you want - I'm not sure *why*) and dynamic SQL (execute immediate).

It is based on Scott's schema; I'm looking for number of appearances of the employee name "KING" in all tables in current schema (querying `USER_TABLES`), within the `ENAME` column (querying `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`).

This is just to give you an idea; feel free to develop it further.

Some sample data:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> select ename from emp order by ename;

ENAME
----------
ALLEN
BLAKE
CLARK
FORD
JAMES
JONES
KING
MARTIN
MILLER
SMITH
TURNER
WARD

12 rows selected.

SQL> select ename from bonus;

ENAME
----------
KING
```

Let's search for that KING person:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(500);
  3    l_cnt number := 0;
  4  begin
  5    for cur_r in (select u.table_name, u.column_name
  6                  from user_tab_columns u, user_tables t
  7                  where u.table_name = t.table_name
  8                    and u.column_name = 'ENAME'
  9                 )
 10    loop
 11      l_str := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || cur_r.table_name ||
 12              ' WHERE ' || cur_r.column_name || ' like (''%KING%'')';
 13
 14      execute immediate (l_str) into l_cnt;
 15
 16      if l_cnt > 0 then
 17        dbms_output.put_line(l_cnt ||' : ' || cur_r.table_name);
 18      end if;
 19    end loop;
 20  end;
 21  /
1 : EMP
1 : BONUS

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

The result says that KING appears once in EMP and BONUS tables.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 100000


----Final OP----------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE StringQuery(names VARCHAR2)
IS
  match_count INTEGER;
  v_data_type VARCHAR2(255) :='VARCHAR2';
  v_search_string VARCHAR2(4000) :=names;

BEGIN
  FOR t IN (SELECT table_name, column_name FROM user_tab_columns where data_type = v_data_type) LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||t.table_name||' WHERE '||t.column_name||' = :1'
    INTO match_count
    USING v_search_string;
    IF match_count > 0 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line( 'Table Name: '||t.table_name ||', Column Name: '||t.column_name||', Found This Many Times: '||match_count );
      --EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT * FROM '||t.table_name||'WHERE '||t.column_name||'='||v_search_string||' ';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
/

CALL StringQuery('&Enter_String_Value');
```